# Mediator pattern and contravariance with Simple Injector

Tags: c#, simple-injector, mediator, mediatr

This question originates from the fact that I'm trying to create a Simple Injector implementation for MediatR: https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/pull/14.

I'm having trouble while trying to resolve implementations of a generic handler interface. Consider the following notification handler interface:

```
public interface INotificationHandler<in TNotification>
    where TNotification : INotification
{
    void Handle(TNotification notification);
}
```

`INotifcation` is just an empty marker interface.

I defined the following handlers for the `Pinged` (which implements `INotification`) event:

```
public class PingedHandler : INotificationHandler<Pinged>
{
    public void Handle(Pinged notification) { }
}

public class PingedHandler2 : INotificationHandler<Pinged>
{
    public void Handle(Pinged notification) { }
}
```

And also a generic handler (notice this should handle every `INotification`):

```
public class GenericHandler : INotificationHandler<INotification>
{
    public void Handle(INotification notification) { }
}
```

With the following registration:

```
var container = new Container();

container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(
    typeof (INotificationHandler<>),
    (service, impls) => container.RegisterAll(service, impls),
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
```

Now I expect:

```
GetAllInstances<INotificationHandler<Pinged>>();
```

to resolve both `PingedHandler` and `PingedHandler2` which it does. But it doesn't resolve the `GenericHandler` since it implements `INotificationHandler<INotification>` and not `INotificationHandler<Pinged>`. I wonder if there is a way to let Simple Injector search up the whole object graph and resolve *anything* that is `Pinged` too.

I've found [a blog post](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=90) from Steven about co-variance and contra-variance, but I'm unable to get it working for my example.

Comment: `INotificationHandler<INotification>` is not compatible with `INotificationHandler<Pinged>` so this isn't surprising. If you want all handlers have you tried `GetAllInstances<INotificationHandler<INotification>>`?

Comment: @Lee `container.GetAllInstances<INotificationHandler<INotification>>()` resolves just the `GenericHandler`, which is what I expect it to do. What I want is that `GenericHandler` always is resolved, since every notification should implement `INotification`.

Comment: @Lee but `INotificationHandler<Pinged>` _is_ compatible with `INotificationHandler<INotification>`.

Comment: @Lee `[Fact]
        public void GenericHandler_CanBe_CalledWithAnInstanceOfPinged()
        {
            var handler = new GenericHandler();

            Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => handler.Handle(new Pinged()));
        }`

Comment: What you are experiencing is a limitation/bug in v2.6. If you upgrade to v2.7.0-beta1 you will see that you can resolve the non-generic `GenericHandler` using the `RegisterAll` registration that @qujck showed in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr: it was a bug/shortcoming in Simple Injector v2.6.0, which is fixed in v2.7.0. The configuration in the question (and shown below) does work now.

---

To summarize @qujck's answer and @Steven's comment: I was able to get it working by installing Simple Injector v2.7.0-beta2 with the following configuration (actually the same as in the question):

```
// Simple Injector v3.x
container.RegisterCollection(typeof(INotificationHandler<>),
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

// Simple Injector v2.x
container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(
    typeof(INotificationHandler<>),
    container.RegisterAll,
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
```

Now Simple Injector is able to resolve `PingedHandler`, `PingedHandler2` *and* the `GenericHandler` when requesting:

```
container.GetAllInstances<INotificationHandler<Pinged>>();
```

Comment: I updated your answer for v2.7.0-beta2. A bug in 2.7.0-beta1 caused the registration to become needlessly complicated. The registration is now what you should expect it to be.

Comment: Thanks for this @Steven! When are you planning to release this?

Comment: Henk, Simple Injector 2.7 has been released.

Comment: IMO this answer should be flagged as 'the' answer.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**

As of Simple Injector release 2.7 [this functionality](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/2.7/advanced.html#covariance-contravariance) is now standard and you no longer require the workaround shown below.

---

You are missing a variation of the `MultipleDispatchEventHandler` described in that article. Taking the basic logic and applying it to your abstractions does give the result you are expecting:

```
[Fact]
public void RegisterAll_Contravariant_Succeeds()
{
    var container = new Container();

    container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(
        typeof(INotificationHandler<>),
        (service, impls) => container.RegisterAll(service, impls),
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

    var handlersType = typeof(IEnumerable<INotificationHandler<Pinged>>);

    var handlersCollection = (
        from r in container.GetCurrentRegistrations()
        where handlersType.IsAssignableFrom(r.ServiceType)
        select r.GetInstance())
        .Cast<IEnumerable<INotificationHandler<Pinged>>>()
        .ToArray();

    var result = 
        from handlers in handlersCollection
        from handler in handlers
        select handler;

    Assert.Equal(3, result.Count());
}
```

But it may be easier to make `GenericHandler` generic:

```
public class GenericHandler<TNotification> : INotificationHandler<TNotification>
    where TNotification : INotification
{
    public void Handle(TNotification notification) { }
}
```

Giving a simpler registration

```
[Fact]
public void RegisterAll_WithOpenAndClosedGenerics_Succeeds()
{
    var container = new Container();

    var types = OpenGenericBatchRegistrationExtensions
        .GetTypesToRegister(
            container,
            typeof(INotificationHandler<>),
            AccessibilityOption.AllTypes,
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        .ToList();

    types.Add(typeof(GenericHandler<>));

    container.RegisterAll(typeof(INotificationHandler<>), types);

    var result = container.GetAllInstances<INotificationHandler<Pinged>>().ToList();

    Assert.Equal(3, result.Count());
}
```